# Can't run RealTimeRoom Google-Play-Games iOS ButtonClicker2000 sample on real device

Tags: ios, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm trying to run Google-Play-Games iOS sample ButtonClicker2000 project on **Real** Device. 
(quickstart: https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/quickstart 
 downloads: https://developers.google.com/games/services/downloads/)

1. The process of signing in to GooglePlayService does not show any
   error.
2. I'm sure that my google console project setted up correctly.
3. I don't have any problem when launching on emulator

**BUT** on a real device (it doesn't matter on iphone or ipad) when i click on quick match button i get this error (at the bottom):

---

```
INFO: Auth operation started: SIGN IN 
NFO: Auth operation SIGN IN finished with status VALID
ERROR: Attempting to get name of an invalid Player 
ERROR: Attempting to get avatar URL of an invalid Player
ERROR: Attempting to get id of an invalid Player
ERROR: Attempting to get title of an invalid Player
ERROR: Attempting to get current xp of an invalid Player
ERROR: Attempting to get last level up timestamp of an invalid Player
ERROR: Attempting to get current level of an invalid Player
ERROR: Attempting to get level number of an invalid PlayerLevel
ERROR: Attempting to get minimum xp of an invalid PlayerLevel
ERROR: Attempting to get maximum xp of an invalid PlayerLevel
ERROR: Attempting to get next level of an invalid Player<br/>
ERROR: Attempting to get level number of an invalid PlayerLevel
ERROR: Attempting to get minimum xp of an invalid PlayerLevel
ERROR: Attempting to get maximum xp of an invalid PlayerLevel
[Core] (Error) __49-[GPGService executeOperation:completionHandler:]_block_invoke:[main] Server Operation Failed [appstate.states.list]
    Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Insufficient Permission)
    Error Full: Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=403 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Insufficient Permission)" UserInfo=0x1758e420 {error=Insufficient Permission, GTLStructuredError=GTLErrorObject 0x175b2e00: {message:"Insufficient Permission" code:403 data:[1]}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Insufficient Permission)}
GooglePlayGames finished signing in!
VERBOSE: Automatically seeded snapshot cache.
VERBOSE: Automatically seeded achievement cache.
VERBOSE: Automatically seeded event cache.
Showing a RTRVC with max players of 4
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <GPGLauncherWindowRootViewController: 0x176cb3c0>.
**INFO: Connect with retry.getRetryAuthToken(): 1
INFO: Token expired.  Refreshing.
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::system_error: condition_variable::timed wait: mutex not locked: Operation not permitted**
```

---

How can i fix this bug? Any help is really appreciated

Comment: Same problem, this is my case https://github.com/playgameservices/ios-basic-samples/issues/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually i've found working solution for this issue. I don't know when exactly but google's guys added "objective c" headers for C++ SDK. These headers are kind of bindings for C++. So the C++ SDK became drag-and-dropable.