# GPGS Started Crashing on iOS 32bit devices Again

Tags: ios, google-play-services, robovm

Recently the iOS part of ROBOVM project started crashing on 32bit devices similar like it was in the past ( [Can't run RealTimeRoom Google-Play-Games iOS ButtonClicker2000 sample on real device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28084324/cant-run-realtimeroom-google-play-games-ios-buttonclicker2000-sample-on-real-de)).

At that time the problem was in sdk itself. And crash was showing up with log message

```
"INFO: Token expired.  Refreshing."
```

Now crashing on the same place in UI quickmatching process. The **difference** this time is in the log. There I see:

```
INFO: Auth operation started: SIGN IN
INFO: Auth operation SIGN IN finished with status VALID
VERBOSE: Automatically seeded snapshot cache.
VERBOSE: Automatically seeded achievement cache.
VERBOSE: Automatically seeded event cache.
INFO: Connect with retry.getRetryAuthToken(): 1
INFO: Token expired.  Refreshing.
VERBOSE: Auth token refresh returned without error.
INFO: Trying to connect with returned auth token.
```

Have someone faced this problem? Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: I am seeing this exact problem when trying to follow the Google Play Games Services C++ guide and running on iOS. :(  
`INFO: Connect with retry.getRetryAuthToken(): 1`
`INFO: Token expired.  Refreshing.`
`Trying to refresh token; old token is: <...>`
`VERBOSE: Kicking off refresh request to main thread now.`
`VERBOSE: Waiting for refresh request to return now.`
`Auth updated!  ... maybe.  New token is: <...>`
`VERBOSE: Refresh request returned.`
`Token refresh success!`
`VERBOSE: Different token!  Refresh successful!`
`INFO: Trying to connect with returned auth token.`

Comment: Having same problem. Could you solve it ?

Comment: Hi, Çağatay Kaya follow https://github.com/playgameservices/ios-basic-samples/issues/1#issuecomment-147513707.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved with new version of GPGS c++ SDK. 
https://developers.google.com/games/services/downloads/sdks